# Why I can't register a client script block of string (url)?

Tags: c#, javascript, .net

Code :

```
string url = "http://www.google.com";
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "UrlSocialDefinitivo", "var UrlSocialDefinitivo=" + Server.UrlEncode(url) + ";", true);
```

but I get (on browser console) : `SyntaxError: identifier starts immediately after numeric literal`.

In fact it registers `UrlSocialDefinitivo=http%3a%2f%2fwww.google.it;`

Where am I wrong? How can I resolve this trouble?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It miss the quotes around the string :

```
string url = "http://www.google.com";
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(
    this, 
    this.GetType(), 
    "UrlSocialDefinitivo", 
    "var UrlSocialDefinitivo=\"" + Server.UrlEncode(url) + "\";",
    true
    );
```

That will produces :

```
UrlSocialDefinitivo="http%3a%2f%2fwww.google.it";
```

Note that I'm not sure you have to keep the `Server.UrlEncore` call. It depends on the format you are expecting actually.

Answer (score 2):

You need to surround the url string in quotes or the javascript interpreter will assume it is javascript to be executed (and fail miserably).

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(),
    "UrlSocialDefinitivo", 
    "var UrlSocialDefinitivo='" + Server.UrlEncode(url) + "';", true);
// quotes               here ^                    and here ^
```